Populating a table based on the contents of an other one without the use of cursors
I am using the Snowflake platform.
I would like to know if it is possible to populate a table based in the content of an other table without the use of cursors. The example given is the most minimal I could come up with in regards to the problem I am facing (meaning the procedure cannot be replaced by a function).
Having this setup:
create or replace table test_1 (num integer);
insert into test_1 values (1), (2), (3);

create or replace table test_2 (num integer, doubled string);

create or replace procedure double_val(val integer)
returns integer
as
begin
    return val * 2;
end;

I would like to populate the table called test_2 based on the contents of test_1, using the procedure to specify the value for the column name doubled.
Meaning that for the current state of test_1, I would like table test_2 to look like this:
|---------------|
| num | doubled |
|----------------
|  1  |    2    |
|  2  |    4    |
|  3  |    6    |
|---------------|

Where the result of the doubled column comes from a call to double_val().
Is this possible without the use of a cursor, preferably in plain SQL syntax?

I don't know snowflake's syntax, but to avoid a procedure need, you could do an INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... type of query. That would be something like: INSERT INTO test_2 SELECT num, num * 2 FROM test_1;

@PaulT. the problem there is that calls to a procedure are not allowed in the select portion. In my real solution the procedure performs more complex operations before returning a value. The example is as minimal as possible to explain the problem.

Not sure what you mean, I'm not using a call to a procedure? I was going with the part where you said preferably in plain SQL syntax, which I took as not wanting a procedure, so what I suggested a way to do so with plain SQL syntax.

Why can't you write a function that calls the procedure?

@McMurphy as I stated, this is a minimal example. The procedure might perform more complex logic in a real  scenario (it does). Think of calling external function or executing DDL statements.

The only way of selecting from a stored procedure is to wrap it in a table function: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/stored-procedure/stored-procedures-selecting-from. If you can’t re-write your SELECT to use this construct you would have to write a UDF instead of a SP - or write the whole thing in a SQL scripting block

The general statement that the procedure can't be written as a function is a bit odd, tbh.  There isn't a lot different about a function and procedure as far as what you can and can't do and you have multiple languages to choose from.

We use Dynamic Tables for something like this. Much like with a view, you can have an underlying transformation with a dynamic table. As you update the values in one table, any parent table would automatically update based on a refresh schedule that you set (the value for target_lag below). So you could do:
create or replace table test_1 (num integer);
insert into test_1 values (1), (2), (3);

create or replace dynamic table test_2
target_lag = '1 minute'
warehouse = warehouse_name
as select num, num*2 as doubled from test_1;

Because you can stack dynamic tables, you can actually have a couple in a row to sort of emulate a procedure. We have a table that has semi-structured data, one that sits on top of that that parses the data, and one that sits on top of that that finds the latest record. It's not the pretty thing, but it does help you to do procedural work with regular old DDL.
